# How to inject more classes in some controller using ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ioc-container, ninject

I am completely new to dependency injection. I am using asp mvc and ninject.
I extended a class from 'DefaultControllerFactory' and added following 'AddBindings' code:

```
private void AddBindings()
        {            
            ninjectKernel.Bind<ICitiesRepository>().To<CitiesRepository>().WithConstructorArgument(
                "connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cstr"].ConnectionString);

            ninjectKernel.Bind<ICountriesRepository>().To<CountriesRepository>().WithConstructorArgument(
                "connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cstr"].ConnectionString);

            ninjectKernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>().WithConstructorArgument(
                "connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cstr"].ConnectionString);

        }
```

In my 'AccountController' I inject IUserRepository via contructor:

```
private IUserRepository userRepository;

        public AccountController(IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
        }
```

And here I come to issue. Account controller contains 'RegisterUser' action. And user must select with standard parameters (username, firstName etc.) a few additianal parameters like Country and City. How to inject more repository classes in some controller? What is the best strategy for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to use Ninject with ASP.NET MVC](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/02/05/how-to-use-ninject-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx)

Here you can find complete tutorial how to setup Ninject with ASP.NET MVC

```
private IUserRepository userRepository;
private IAddressRepository addressRepository;

        public AccountController(IUserRepository userRepository, IAddressRepository addressRepository)
        {
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
            this.addressRepository = addressRepository;
        }
```

Comment: That is tutorial about how to setup ninject. But I set it up I just don't know how to insert more dependency classes in one controller?

Comment: You can use as much repositories in the constructor as you need. Chec\k the sample.